# Connect to postgres from google script

Tags: google-apps-script

Mysql protocol and support in jdbc.https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc How can I use postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. The documentation only lists these four:

1. MySQL
2. MSSQL
3. Oracle Database
4. Cloud SQL

However, you can leverage google cloud functions to create a custom service that can connect to a postgres database. You can then call that service using Google Apps Script.